# Passing arrays through ParamArray with user-defined functions

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, parameter-passing, paramarray

New to VBA. I'm having two issues with the following code for user defined functions. I can't figure out how to pass arrays through ParamArray.

1) <s>The printed type from bool() is 8203 as it should be. But the printed type from test() is 8204, so they're null or invalid.</s> Edit: it was pointed out that 8204 is due to the Variant type.

2) I'm not sure if I'm calling elements from nested arrays correctly with "A(0)(1,1)". I'm not able to print or call values from A() the the Test() function.

In a cell formula:

```
=Test(bool())
```

In VBA editor:

```
Function Test(ParamArray A() As Variant)
    Debug.Print VarType(A)
    Debug.Print A(0)(1,1)
    Test = A(0)(1, 1)
End Function

Function bool()
    Dim out() As Boolean
    Dim u As Integer, v As Integer

    ReDim out(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
    For v = 1 To 2
        For u = 1 To 3
            out(u, v) = True
        Next u
    Next v

    Debug.Print VarType(out)
    bool = out
End Function
```

ParamArray is necessary, I'm just not demonstrating why with this example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by removing the Debug.Print A(0). And by fixing another typo that was not present in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

> **8204** is [expected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)  because `ParamArray A() As Variant` is a ***variant*** array.

vbVariant = **12**
 vbArray = **8192**

**8192 + 12 = 8204**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206221/discussion-on-answer-by-profoundlyoblivious-passing-arrays-through-paramarray-wi).

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues, first A(0) is param 1 and the content is out(u,v), so
debug.print A(0) will give error, second your function test without return value
and for running code are as follow:

```
Function Test(ParamArray A() As Variant)
    msgbox "1" & ubound(A)
    Debug.Print A(0)(1, 1)
    Test = A(0)(1, 1)
    msgbox "2" & ubound(A)
End Function

Function bool()
    Dim out() As Boolean
    Dim u As Integer, v As Integer

    ReDim out(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
    For v = 1 To 2
        For u = 1 To 3
            out(u, v) = True
        Next u
    Next v

    Debug.Print VarType(out)
    bool = out
End Function
```

Comment: OK for param array you can use the first code i created, but you must remove the debug.print A(0) first, can you please to show the last of your code for function test? In my code I put ' to debug.print A(0) to be indicated as remark, this can be removed

Comment: and if you need return value, you must give test=A(0)(1,1) as return value to cell caller

Comment: OK try to change the function test as in my last change, what happen?, would you please inform me

Comment: what the content of the first message?

Comment: it means you get 1 param, it was right, and try to change the first msgbox to msgbox (A(0)(1,1)) what happen, any error message, what is it?

Comment: it's strange, usually if any error it will give error message. OK you try to make a sub, and run from the sub:  Sub test2()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = bool()
    MsgBox myArray(1, 1)
    MsgBox (Test(bool()))
End Sub

Comment: in mine, if any error, it will give #VALUE! and no message, it's normal. And in my cell formula: = test(bool())